# Is it a good idea to email a potential grad adviser a modified motivation essay after I have submitted my application?

Tags: statement-of-purpose, physics, electrical-engineering

I am applying for a master's program in electrical engineering/applied physics. After I submitted my motivational essay, I felt that I could have talked more about my experience. Is it a good idea to email my potential adviser a modified essay?

Comment: Is a motivation essay really about experiences? Wouldn't the potential advisor have a close look on both essays to see what you've modified?

Comment: In the prompt, they ask that an applicant talk about his/her experience....Sure, the advisor could look. There would be no discrepancies between the two essays. The second one would only contain more details on my adacemic experience.

Comment: No it's a bad idea. You would look like someone who can't follow procedures and no-one's interested in your motivational essay anyway.